# What's the graph relation? #1

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, graph-theory

What is the relation that connects the nodes of this digraph?

[image]

Comment: I think there is a typo in the question. It shouldn't be "diagraph" right?

Comment: Thanks for checking up on my spelling. "[Digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)" is actually what I intended. It is an abbreviation of "directed graph".

Comment: Oh okok sorry I didn't know that abbreviation.

Comment: No problem at all. Every discipline has its own jargon that confuses everyone else :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Node $i$ goes to node $i+s(i)$, where $s(i)$ is the sum of the proper divisors of $i$

Comment: Nice math knowledge! You nailed it, and used the correct jargon to boot!

Comment: Note: $s(n)+n=\sigma(n)$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function))