# What's the graph relation? #3

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, graph-theory

What's the relation that joins the nodes?

[image]

Previous

- [What's the graph relation? #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97643/whats-the-graph-relation-1)
- [What's the graph relation? #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97644/whats-the-graph-relation-2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Sum the digits of node $i$ to get the outgoing neighbor $j$.